# Django login function not working when server run on host 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, django, authentication

```
def UserLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            username = request.POST["username"]
            cif = request.POST["cif"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = Users.objects.get(username=username)

            if user :
                if user.role == '001':
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('webapp:bank-details')
                elif user.role == '002':
                    login(request, user)

                    json = {
                        "service": "CORE_BANKING_LOGIN",
                        "request": {
                            "username": f"{username}",
                            "cif": f"{cif}",
                            "password": f"{password}",
                            "channelType": "CORPORATE"
                        }
                    }
```

this is the code ive been using to log users in when using the localhost to run the server but ive discovered that when i run it using the host 0.0.0.0 i couldnt log in anymore, can someone help or explain why

i tried specifying the authentication backend in my settings but that didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that 0.0.0.0 isn't a real valid IP address to have in your session cookie. I recommend that you try to reach your server by your private IP address instead, e.g., 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x.

On a side note, your code isn't checking for a password, so it allows anyone to log in once they have a username.

Comment: Thank you, im just from trying what you suggested but the result is still the same, initialially i had a custom authentication backend but i tried to simplify the authentication process as much as possible but still

Comment: Are you sending a POST request?

Comment: yes i am, might i highlight- when i run the application using 127.0.0.1 :8000 i have no problems, but i need the project to be accessible within the local network

Answer (score 0):

Following check will help you to identify issue.

- Check the path of session cookie in browser. it should match with host URL.
  [image]
- Is your service running using gunicorn or any other server, using multiple workers. in this case run the server with 1 worker only to identify the issue.